# Extracting tokens from a string with regular expressions in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex, algorithm

I'm curious if this is even possible with Regex.  I want to extract tokens from a string similar to:

```
Select a [COLOR] and a [SIZE].
```

Ok, easy enough - I can use `(\[[A-Z]+\])`

However, I want to also extract the text between the tokens.  Basically, I want the matched groups for the above to be:

```
"Select a "
"[COLOR]"
" and a "
"[SIZE]"
"."
```

What's the best approach for this?  If there's a way to do this with RegEx, that would be great.  Otherwise, I'm guessing I have to extract the tokens, then manually loop through the MatchCollection and parse out the substrings based on the indexes and lengths of each Match.  Please note I need to preserve the order of the strings and tokens.  Is there a better algorithm to do this sort of string parsing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Regex.Split(s, @"(\[[A-Z]+\])")` - it should give you the exact array you're after. Split takes captured groups and converts them to tokens in the result array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method without using regular expressions (`Regex`) that uses `String.Split`, but you lose the delimiters.

```
        string s = "Select a [COLOR] and a [SIZE].";

        string[] sParts = s.Split('[', ']');

        foreach (string sPart in sParts)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(sPart);
        }

        // Select a 
        // COLOR
        //  and a 
        // SIZE
        // .
```